# Bootstrap DatePicker: From-To Synchronization with Erased Text Event

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker, bootstrap-datepicker

I have 2 Bootstrap DatePickers (From/To) where the selection in each needs to follow the Before-After rule.

Two questions:

1) I accomplished it with `on('changeDate')` but I also need to capture the **Text Erase** event. If the text is erased, the Min/Max in each should go to the default limits of 01/01/2010 -> 01/01/2050.

2) I also have this question: Initally, I attach the `on('changeDate')` when first creating these datepickers. Then I have the `Destroy and Regenerate` button which will `.destroy()` and re-create these pickers, **without** the prior handlers. However, I see that the onChange behavior is retained. Why is it retained, if I destroyed the controls and never re-specified it on regeneration?

```js
 $('#awardDateRangeStart').datepicker({
   format: "mm/dd/yyyy",
   startDate: "01/01/2010",
   endDate: "01/01/2050",    
   autoclose: true, 
   orientation: 'bottom', 
   startView: "days", 
   minViewMode: "days"   
 }).on('changeDate', function(){
     // set the "toDate" start to not be later than "fromDate" ends:
     $('#awardDateRangeEnd').datepicker('setStartDate', new Date($(this).val()));
 });    
  
  $('#awardDateRangeEnd').datepicker({
   format: "mm/dd/yyyy",
   startDate: "01/01/2010",
   endDate: "01/01/2050",    
   autoclose: true, 
   orientation: 'bottom', 
   startView: "days", 
   minViewMode: "days"   
 }).on('changeDate', function(){
     // set the "fromDate" end to not be later than "toDate" starts:
     $('#awardDateRangeStart').datepicker('setEndDate', new Date($(this).val()));
 });  
  
  
$('#regenerate').click(function() {
   $('#awardDateRangeStart').val('');
   $('#awardDateRangeEnd').val('');
   $('#awardDateRangeStart').datepicker("destroy");
   $('#awardDateRangeEnd').datepicker("destroy");
   // Recreate WITHOUT on-changeDate handler
  $('#awardDateRangeStart').datepicker({
   format: "mm/dd/yyyy",
   startDate: "01/01/2010",
   endDate: "01/01/2050",    
   autoclose: true, 
   orientation: 'bottom', 
   startView: "days", 
   minViewMode: "days"  });  
  $('#awardDateRangeEnd').datepicker({
   format: "mm/dd/yyyy",
   startDate: "01/01/2010",
   endDate: "01/01/2050",    
   autoclose: true, 
   orientation: 'bottom', 
   startView: "days", 
   minViewMode: "days"  });       
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.6.1/css/bootstrap-datepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.6.1/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>

FROM <input type="text" id="awardDateRangeStart" />
TO <input type="text" id="awardDateRangeEnd" />

<button id="regenerate">Destroy &amp; Recreate Datepickers</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

if I got your problem right, you want to have a selected date as limit or default date if there is no selected date is that right ?

if so, can you use a function inside

```
('#awardDateRangeEnd').datepicker('setStartDate', new Date($(this).val()));
```

like

```
('#awardDateRangeEnd').datepicker('setStartDate', function (){
  if($(this).val()){
       return new Date($(this).val()) }  
  else {
       return yourDefaultDate
       }
 });
```

for second question I am not able to regenerate the issue in jsFiddle

Comment: It's in the attached StackOverflow code snippet. Click the button, and the handler **still** applies. But in the generation code I don't reattach it.

Comment: weirdly it still works fine for me even in code snippet, I select a date, it puts restriction, I click clear button, restrictions are removed, if this is how you are doing, let me know which browser you are using

Comment: Hi, the restrictions are removed from the first example, BUT if you select a new Date1, the Date2 will observe the restriction. But no restrictions should be observed anymore. Here's the test: 1) Select D1, 2) D2 is restricted, 3) click Regenerate, 4) Select D1, 5) D2 is restricted - but these are brand new controls without the handler now.

Comment: oh ok, I get the question now, ok this is how I think its suppose to work(unless something weird can be done), because if you think about it you define code for same element (Selector).datepicker() essentially what that does is call that function for that selector and that function is still there even when you destroy it, I will do some research because this is really interesting but for now it seems like it is working the way it is supposed to work